# i wrote a program for alert and prompt in replit Node.js it showed an error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a program for alert and prompt in replit Node.js it showed an error
It said that alert and prompt isn't described in replit
my code-

```
let a = prompt("Hey what is your age?")
a = Number.parseInt(a)
if a<0 {
   alert("This is a valid age")          
}
else {
  alert("this is an invalid age")
}
```

It's not a syntax error.

I don't know what to try.

Comment: `alert` and `prompt` are available in a browser environment, not in Node.js

Comment: `prompt` and `alert` are browser functions.

Comment: `if a<0 {` is a syntax error, though.